# Build C++20 on mac OS 11

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, c++20

Is this possible? I've been trying for days.

I tried to use homebrew's clang compiler, running this:

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S . -B cmake-build-release  -Wno-dev -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$CC -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$CXX
cmake --build ./cmake-build-release --config Release
```

eventually leads to `lipo` being called, where it complains:

```
warning: Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: Invalid value (Producer: 'LLVM15.0.6' Reader: 'LLVM APPLE_1_1300.0.29.3_0')
fatal error: Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/PluginProcessor-eb9c16/PluginProcessor-arm64.o
```

---

I believe `lipo` is being called because I added this to my cmake project:

```
    set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64;x86_64")
```

(This is for a universal build)

I was trying to setup a symlink to point `lipo` to `llvm-lipo` but had no luck (and I wasn't sure if this would even fix this error anyway).

---

If I try to use `-G Xcode` (the XCode project generator) I get the error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: .../Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
CMake Error in cmake-build-xcode/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "cmTC_e6c65" requires the language dialect "CXXc++2a" (with compiler
  extensions).  But the current compiler "AppleClang" does not support this,
  or CMake does not know the flags to enable it.
```

---

I think the best solution would be to somehow get Xcode to use the homebrew Clang compiler - rather than Apple Clang; is this possible?

---

I was also thinking to overwrite the `clang` executables included with XCode with symlinks to the HomeBrew clang. This might fix but again seems hackey - when I was trying to setup symlinks to `lipo` I had to setup weird security stuff / boot mac OS into recovery mode - which is where I gave up

Comment: Have you checked that the version of LLVM you want to use supports the features of C++20 that you want to use? No compiler has full support for C++20, and LLVM in particular seems to be lagging the most.

Comment: @sweenish yes, it does. The only problem I had when using LLVM was that lipo (the tool from xcode that combines the output into a single universal binary) reverted to using AppleClang - which couldn't read the output from LLVM Clang

Comment: I am failing to see how your first command invokes the LLVM clang. By default, installing LLVM via homebrew does not insert itself into your path, and certainly not into your environmental variables. Invoking cmake via `sudo` also raises a flag with me. Hopefully someone with more experience with Xcode can offer more meaningful help. I have feeling that if you want aa Universal binary, you have to play in Apple's playground.

Comment: @sweenish I also suspected the sudo command (and I remembered that sudo doesn't propagate environment variables (I had CC and CXX variables setup). After removing the sudo, I made progress - I have a different error now

Comment: @sweenish I also suspected the sudo command (and I remembered that sudo doesn't propagate environment variables (I had CC and CXX variables setup). For the XCode build, after I removed `sudo`, I got passed the error saying apple-clang can't build `cxx20` but then I still got compile errors (I think xcode is still internally using apple-clang). Removing sudo changed nothing for the llvm build (no xcode generator)

Comment: You can build each architecture separately, and then use `add_custom_target` to use `llvm-lipo` manually.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep is this binary as efficient? `lipo` seems to work directly with Mach-O files

Comment: @Tobiq I don't know if Apple's version of LLVM is more optimized or not, but weren't you trying to setup a symlink to point `lipo` to `llvm-lipo` anyways?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep the build fails when trying to build one at a time - I give up, im going to try upgrading to Mac OS 12 so I can use the latest XCode